# Signing the JNLP file

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, digital-certificate

I am running the java web start application. since the application digital signature has been expired. I have purchase the signature from the CA and signed my jar file using storetype as pkcs12.

After signing all the jar used in JNLP file and started the application. Still the security warning popup appears and prompt a message as "The Application's digital signature has expired". When i click to read "more information" link from the popup, it says "Part of the application is missing a digital signature. And also "application's associated file (JNLP) does not have one".

So i plan to SIGN MY JNLP file also.  To sign my JNLP file, i have followed this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/signedJNLP.html).
From the document

> "To create a signed JNLP file you don't sign the JNLP file itself, but
>   you include the JNLP file inside the directory structure before the
>   JAR file is created and then signed. The JNLP file must be named
>   APPLICATION.JNLP and is included in the JNLP-INF subdirectory"

As document I have added the folder named as "JNLP-INF" and added a file named "APPLICATION.JNLP".

Here is my folder structure

Tomcat

```
  webapps

         application_name(xxxx)

                      Client-lib ( all the jars inside is signed)
                      JNLP-INF ( has APPLICATION.JNLP)
                      META-INF
                      WEB-INF
                      client.jnlp
                      index.html
```

In the build.xml,copied the test.jnlp to /JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP and  signing the jar files.

Still i am getting the message in warning security popup as ""The Application's digital signature has expired"

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to get your CA to issue you a new (non-expired) certificate. How to do this will vary based on your CA. If your certificate is, indeed, not expired, this should not cost you anything. But your certificate is only as valid as how long you've paid them for.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure we cleaned up all the cache for the applets and applications. 
To do this procees, go to control panel -> java -> Temporary internet files -> settings -> delete files -> check the check boxes for Cached applications and applets and Installed applications and applets.

This will make sure, your cache is clear and now start your services and check the jar signing .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe signing your JNLP would help. You should instead resign all the jars of your application.

Comment: Yes. We should not sign the JNLP. We have sign only jar. But we should copy the jnlp file to the location JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct about this and understood you correctly, you need to put `/JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP` inside your `.jar` an then sign it. Afterwards copy it to a custom location and start it. This *should* help.

The `.jnlp` itself is not signed, but the copy of it can be matched against the `APPLICATION.JNLP` inside the **signed** `.jar`